# Adding CSS class to flagged node teasers

Tags: theming, flags

I have tried the following code corolla theme's template.php

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node().
 */
function corolla_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $flag = flag_get_flag('sold'); // Machine name of your flag.
  if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($variables['node']->nid)) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-flag-sold';
  }
}
```

This is supposed to add CSS class="node-flag-sold" next to "node". But looking through my firebug, there arenosuch classes added.

Please note, that my node--content-type.tpl.php is custom rewritten.  Do I need to add anything there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocess code looks reasonably correct.

Make sure you're printing out the `$classes` variable in your custom `node--content-type.tpl.php`

e.g, in the wrapper div here:

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

<!-- Node template content ... --> 

</div><!-- /.node -->
```

If curious, `$variables['classes_array']` is flattened into `$variables['classes']` in [`template_process`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process/7https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process/7) with

```
// Flatten out classes.
$variables['classes'] = implode(' ', $variables['classes_array']);
```

In D7, process functions are introduced, running after preprocess functions.